# `purrr` alternative to row-wise function that determines event date based on complex rule set

Tags: r, function, date, purrr, rowwise

I am working with a client that wants to provide an input spreadsheet with a text description of when certain events should occur in a given year. Each event (and there are at least 200 of them) is a separate row, containing a complex rule set about when it should occur, e.g., *"the first Saturday before October 1st"* or *"the Friday closest to December 1st"*. There are also a few times when the event simply occurs on a particular date, but this is rare. However, the actual spreadsheet has about 15 columns that control the start dates of each event, so the logic I need to use to compute the start dates gets pretty in-depth.

I've come up with a way to compute the start dates using a function and a loop that iterates over each row of my `data.frame`, but I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient `tidyverse` or `purrr` solution to this problem. Is it possible (or advisable) to vectorize a solution to this problem?

This is my current (working) solution for the smallest, most compact example I could imagine. Can I make this more efficient, and readable for my more complex real-world input?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Bring in demo data that describes 3 events, and when they should each start.

demo <- structure(list(Event = c("Gala", "Celebration", "Wrap-up"), date_start
= structure(c(18871, NA, NA), class = "Date"), weekday_near = c(NA,
"Saturday", "Friday" ), near_description = c(NA, "before", "closest to"),
near_date = structure(c(NA, 18901, 18962), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what the `demo` data look like:

```
Event       date_start weekday_near near_description near_date 
Gala        2021-09-01 NA           NA               NA        
Celebration NA         Saturday     before           2021-10-01
Wrap-up     NA         Friday       closest to       2021-12-01
```

Now, determine start dates for each event - the Gala, the Celebration, and the Wrap-up.

```
# Create a tibble that contains all possible dates for these events this year.

datedb <- tibble(date = seq(make_date(2021, 9, 1), make_date(2021, 12, 31), by = 1),
                 wday = wday(date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE))


# Write function meant to determine event date for each row of the dataframe.

determine_date <- function(df){
  
  # define variables that are easier to read
  # this part makes me squeamish - 
  # there's gotta be a better way to do this with the tidyverse
  event_date_exact <- df[["date_start"]]
  event_near_wday <- df[["weekday_near"]]
  event_near_desc <- df[["near_description"]]
  event_near_date <- df[["near_date"]]
  
  # Event date - if there is an exact date for the event, choose it as the event date.
  if (!is.na(event_date_exact)) {
    event_date <- event_date_exact
  
  # Otherwise, if the date is dependent on another date, figure out when it should be:
  } else {
    event_date_vec <- datedb %>% filter(wday == event_near_wday) %>% pull(date)
    event_date <- 
      case_when(
        # If you're looking for the closest weekday to a particular date:
        event_near_desc == "closest to" ~ event_date_vec[which(abs(event_date_vec - event_near_date) == 
                         min(abs(event_date_vec - event_near_date), na.rm = TRUE))],
        # If you're looking for the first weekday before that weekday
        event_near_desc == "before" ~ rev(event_date_vec[which(event_date_vec - event_near_date < 0)])[1],
        # If neither of these worked, output NA to check why 
        TRUE ~ NA_Date_
      )
       }
}

# create empty vector to store results
start_dates <- lubridate::ymd()

for (i in 1:nrow(demo)) {
  start_dates[i] <- determine_date(demo[i,])
}

# add start dates back to original demo dataframe
demo$start_date <- start_dates
```

#### Desired output:

Note new `start_date` column

```
demo

Event       date_start weekday_near near_description near_date    start_date
Gala        2021-09-01 NA           NA               NA           2021-09-01
Celebration NA         Saturday     before           2021-10-01   2021-09-25
Wrap-up     NA         Friday       closest to       2021-12-01   2021-12-03
```

Comment: Hi, the following will get rid of the loop.  `demo %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(start_dates = determine_date(.data))`.  I personally don't know if `rowwise` is considered vectorized or not, but I find it easier than trying to use `purrr` for row operations. The only way I've used `purrr` rowwise is first splitting the data with `split` by row first.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I keep reading that `rowwise` might become deprecated, so I was trying to be cautious and not use it, as I want the code to work for many years in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to vectorize a function, under the hood it is really just making a call to `mapply`. So, if you want to use `purrr` style coding, you maybe just want to modify your function arguments as follows:

The setup:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

# Bring in demo data that describes 3 events, and when they should each start.

demo <- structure(list(Event = c("Gala", "Celebration", "Wrap-up"), date_start
                       = structure(c(18871, NA, NA), class = "Date"), weekday_near = c(NA,
                                                                                       "Saturday", "Friday" ), near_description = c(NA, "before", "closest to"),
                       near_date = structure(c(NA, 18901, 18962), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                  -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

datedb <- tibble(date = seq(make_date(2021, 9, 1), make_date(2021, 12, 31), by = 1),
                 wday = wday(date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE))
```

Here is refactored version of your function.

Using `case_when` as opposed to a `switch` statement is really up to you. I opted to use `switch` since this function is intended to be called within a pmap call, i.e. we expect it to only check a single value.

```r
#write a function that expects 4 input values
#vectorize/pmap over each.
determine_date2 <- function(date_start, weekday_near, near_desc, near_date){
  event_vec <- datedb %>% filter(wday == weekday_near) %>% pull(date)
  event_date <-
    if(!is.na(date_start)){
      date_start
    } else if(!is.na(near_desc)){
      switch(
        near_desc,
        `closest to` = event_vec[which(abs(event_vec - near_date) == min(abs(event_vec - near_date), na.rm = TRUE))],
        before = rev(event_vec[which(event_vec - near_date < 0)])[1],
        NA_Date_
      )
    } else {
      NA_Date_
    }
  event_date
}
```

I actually just discovered that there isn't really a `pmap_date` variant, but what I produced below should suffice as a substitute.

```r
pmap_date <- function(.l, .f, ...){
  res <- pmap(.l, .f, ...)
  check_res <- map_lgl(res, ~is.Date(.x)&&is_scalar_vector(.x))
  if(!all(check_res)){
    rlang::abort(glue::glue("all results must return a scalar date. offending entries: ",glue::glue_collapse("{!which(check_res)}", sep = ", ")))
  }
  
  return(reduce(res, c))
}
```

Now we should be able to use `pmap_date` inside a mutate function

```r
demo %>%
  mutate(
    start_dates = pmap_date(list(date_start, weekday_near, near_description, near_date), determine_date2)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   Event       date_start weekday_near near_description near_date  start_dates
#>   <chr>       <date>     <chr>        <chr>            <date>     <date>     
#> 1 Gala        2021-09-01 <NA>         <NA>             NA         2021-09-01 
#> 2 Celebration NA         Saturday     before           2021-10-01 2021-09-25 
#> 3 Wrap-up     NA         Friday       closest to       2021-12-01 2021-12-03
```

If you prefer, you can make your "vectorized" wrapper function as if you called the `Vectorize` function yourself:

```r
v_determine_date2 <- function(date_start, weekday_near, near_desc, near_date) pmap_date(list(date_start, weekday_near, near_desc, near_date), determine_date2)

demo %>%
  mutate(
    start_dates = v_determine_date2(date_start, weekday_near, near_description, near_date)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   Event       date_start weekday_near near_description near_date  start_dates
#>   <chr>       <date>     <chr>        <chr>            <date>     <date>     
#> 1 Gala        2021-09-01 <NA>         <NA>             NA         2021-09-01 
#> 2 Celebration NA         Saturday     before           2021-10-01 2021-09-25 
#> 3 Wrap-up     NA         Friday       closest to       2021-12-01 2021-12-03
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much Justin! I have a few questions/comments. Will this still work with `case_when`? In my real example, I have more than two conditions where you have `switch`. Also, in my real example, the spreadsheet has BOTH start dates, and end dates. These have different column names, but are in the same row. I've dealt with this by giving the function an argument, "start date" or "end date" and then defining the columns within the function (as in my example). How would you deal with this?

Comment: I suppose one idea would be to reshape (`pivot_longer`) the table to have a column that indicates whether it is a "start date" or "end date", then make the column names the same no matter whether it is a start or end date.

Comment: It should work just fine with `case_when`, again, I was writing this with a very specific goal in mind, to vectorize. As for the start_date/end_date, I'm unsure without an example. If you revise your post, I may be of more help.

Comment: I'm going to play around with a few ideas first. Thanks again!

Comment: A rejoinder: Justin, your solution should work very well for me and I've learned from your suggested solution. For anyone interested in the issue of `pmap` stripping the date class, you can check out https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358. Justin while this question has't received a lot of attention, if you think it deserves an upvote, I'd surly appreciate it!